# Jquery jplayer circle player scaling

Tags: jquery, jplayer

circle player - brilliant, stylish.
circle player - too big.

I have successfully scaled the skin and the css but....

I can't work out how to scale the transforms for the progress bar.

I am scaling by 50% to make life easy for myself.

All help gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as a quick and dirty solution, you can apply

```
-webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
-moz-transform: scale(0.5);
-ms-transform: scale(0.5);
-o-transform: scale(0.5);
transform: scale(0.5);
```

to the `cp_container`.